# How to create Solr Query with SolrJClient for the below JSON?

Tags: solr, solrj

Actuall I am able to hit the local solr via postman , but unable to do same with Solr J Client for the below query . Can some help Howshould I create this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "edismax": {
                        "query": "\"market value\"",
                        "qf": "title^10",
                        "tie": "0.1",
                        "mm": "100%"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "edismax": {
                        "query": "market+value",
                        "qf": "title^2",
                        "tie": "0.1",
                        "mm": "100%"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "edismax": {
                        "query": "(market* AND value*)",
                        "qf": "title^5",
                        "tie": "0.1",
                        "mm": "100%"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "edismax": {
                        "query": "(market~ AND value~)",
                        "qf": "title^1",
                        "tie": "0.1",
                        "mm": "100%"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "edismax": {
                        "query": "{!knn f=title_vector topK=100}[-0.019111417, -0.025036218, 0.0041847187, -0.013134183]}]}
```

I have tried below way :
`query {!bool should=$ref1 should=$ref2 should=$ref3}&ref1=title:"Market Value"&ref2=title:Market+Value&ref3=(title:Market* AND title:Value*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr does provide option doing query in json format and also there solrJ query construction samples.

Click [here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-query-dsl.html#nested-boolean-query-example) for solr official doc page.

For eg:

Curl Json query:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/query -d '
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"lucene": {"df": "name", query: "iPod"}}
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {"frange": {"l": "0", "u": "5", "query": "popularity"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```

SolrJ

```
final Map<String, Object> queryTopLevel = new HashMap<>();
final Map<String, Object> boolProperties = new HashMap<>();
final List<Object> mustClauses = new ArrayList<>();
final List<Object> mustNotClauses = new ArrayList<>();
final Map<String, Object> frangeTopLevel = new HashMap<>();
final Map<String, Object> frangeProperties = new HashMap<>();

queryTopLevel.put("bool", boolProperties);
boolProperties.put("must", mustClauses);
mustClauses.add("name:iPod");

boolProperties.put("must_not", mustNotClauses);
frangeTopLevel.put("frange", frangeProperties);
frangeProperties.put("l", 0);
frangeProperties.put("u", 5);
frangeProperties.put("query", "popularity");
mustNotClauses.add(frangeTopLevel);

final JsonQueryRequest query = new JsonQueryRequest().setQuery(queryTopLevel);
final QueryResponse response = query.process(solrClient, COLLECTION_NAME);

final Map<String, Object> queryTopLevel = new HashMap<>();
final Map<String, Object> boolProperties = new HashMap<>();
final List<Object> mustClauses = new ArrayList<>();
final List<Object> mustNotClauses = new ArrayList<>();
final Map<String, Object> frangeTopLevel = new HashMap<>();
final Map<String, Object> frangeProperties = new HashMap<>();

queryTopLevel.put("bool", boolProperties);
boolProperties.put("must", mustClauses);
mustClauses.add("name:iPod");
```